# Window service C# - Refresh issue

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, c#-4.0, windows-services

I am scheduling a windows service to pick a file from a path to load in that SQL server. I am using datatable to write into the SQL server. While picking the first file from path to load is fine, When doing the second time or after couple of time facing an exception

When i debug im not facing this kind of exception, the column created by is added once in datatable. Is this is a cache issue or mistake from my end?

Note when i restart the service it is working fine without exceptions after some time same exceptions occurring

Exception in log:

> A column named 'SGC#1_Created_By' already belongs to this DataTable.
> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
try
{
    var columnDetails = GetTemplateColumn(UserId, lbtempid[tbl], DBConnection);
    SqlConnection bulkcon = new SqlConnection(DBEncryption);                
    bulkcon.Open();
    using (SqlTransaction transaction = bulkcon.BeginTransaction())
    {

        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlbc = new SqlBulkCopy(bulkcon, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction))
        {
            DataTable _table = new DataTable();
            _table = DsLocalBorrowingTbl.Tables[tbl];
            for (int _tbl = 0; _tbl < columnDetails.Count; _tbl++)
            {
                sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add(columnDetails[_tbl].APL_MAS_CRA_Column_Name.Trim(), columnDetails[_tbl].APL_MAS_CRA_Column_Name.Trim());
            }
            sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("SGC#1_Created_By", "SGC#1_Created_By");
            sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("SGC#2_Created_On", "SGC#2_Created_On");
            sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("SGC#3_IsProcessed", "SGC#3_IsProcessed");
            sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add("SGC#4_Processed_On", "SGC#4_Processed_On");
            System.Data.DataColumn newColumn = new System.Data.DataColumn("SGC#1_Created_By", typeof(System.Int32));
            newColumn.DefaultValue = UserId;
            _table.Columns.Add(newColumn);
            System.Data.DataColumn newColumn1 = new System.Data.DataColumn("SGC#2_Created_On", typeof(System.DateTime));
            newColumn1.DefaultValue = DateTime.Now;
            _table.Columns.Add(newColumn1);
            System.Data.DataColumn newColumn2 = new System.Data.DataColumn("SGC#3_IsProcessed", typeof(System.Int32));
            newColumn2.DefaultValue = 0;
            _table.Columns.Add(newColumn2);
            System.Data.DataColumn newColumn3 = new System.Data.DataColumn("SGC#4_Processed_On", typeof(System.DateTime));
            newColumn3.DefaultValue = DateTime.Now;
            _table.Columns.Add(newColumn3);
            SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(DBConnection);
            sqlbc.DestinationTableName = "iCon." + lbsheet[tbl].Trim();
            sqlbc.WriteToServer(_table);
            sqlConn.Close();


            sqlConn.Open();
         
            int ErrorListId = GetErrorListLastIdentity(DBConnection);
            _LBErrocount += 1;
          DsLocalBorrowingTbl.Tables[tbl].Rows.Count, DsLocalBorrowingTbl.Tables[tbl].Rows.Count, DBConnection, 1);
            int statusCount = Convert.ToInt32(DsLocalBorrowingTbl.Tables[tbl].Rows.Count);
            transaction.Commit();
            _rowcount += DsLocalBorrowingTbl.Tables[tbl].Rows.Count;
        }
    }
    bulkcon.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    WriteToFile(" StartExcelOperations_LocalBorrowing_Insertion error :" + ex.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Smells like a threading issue.

Comment: How we can avoid this ..plz help

Comment: There is not enough code to deduce the problem... STOP... before you paste your whole solution or oodles of unrelated code, thinking about what is relevant to the immediate problem, how you load this data, what is triggering the load (event) ect

Comment: The service is checking the file in a path continuously.if the file comes it starts it process and loading the data. There is a chances of many file coming at few second intervals

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are first creating the data table, and then overwriting it with one from, i guess a static class. Any subsequent calls to this function should produce the problem. Either remove the 2nd line, or add the columns once in a initialization function.

```
DataTable _table = new DataTable();
_table = DsLocalBorrowingTbl.Tables[tbl];
```